# file open failed when persist data to internal storage

Tags: android, performance

I am trying to persist data into my Android app's internal storage.

My code is:

```
File dir = context.getDir("dataDir", context.MODE_PRIVATE);
File file = new File(dir, "myData");

FileOutputStream fos = null;
ObjectOutputStream oos = null;

fos = new FileOutputStream(file); //Exception here
oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
oos.writeObject(MY_DATA);
oos.flush();
...
...
```

But I got the following **exception** when open `FileOutputStream`:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundExceptoin ..., open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
02-19 12:18:23.006: V/MyApp(21019):     at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:427)
02-19 12:18:23.006: V/MyApp(21019):     at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:88)
02-19 12:18:23.006: V/MyApp(21019):     at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:73)
```

Why it throws this exception ? Where am I wrong?

**======UPDATE (solution)=======**

After tried all the answers below, I don't have any luck, but eventually, I got the problem solved. The thing is this:

I have a separate class for persistence:

```
public MyClass{
 private Context context;  

 private File dir;
 private File file;

 public MyClass(Context context){
   this.context = context;

   // I used to initialize dir & file instances here
   dir = context.getDir("dataDir", context.MODE_PRIVATE);
   file = new File(dir, "myData");
 }

 public void persistData(){
    //Seems I have to initiate dir & file in this function, then it works
    dir = context.getDir("dataDir", context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    file = new File(dir, "myData");

    //I used to have the following code without above 2 lines, which is not working
    FileOutputStream fos = null;
    ObjectOutputStream oos = null;

    fos = new FileOutputStream(file); //Exception here
    oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
    oos.writeObject(MY_DATA);
    oos.flush();
    ...
    ...
 }

}
```

I do this for persistence:

```
MyClass my = new MyClass(context);
my.persistData();
```

I used to initialize `dir` & `file` in constructor, and access the instance in different functions of MyClass, but seems I have to initialize them in each function, then it works. But not sure the reason behind this.... if someone could explain to me.

Comment: I guess your file needs an extension like myData.txt

Comment: have you added this permission 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_INTERNAL_STORAGE" />

Comment: That permission [doesn't exist](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html).

Comment: @Leem.fin Interesting! Only explanation I can think of is that you're getting different paths. Can you print `file.getAbsolutePath()` in your constructor (after `file` is initialized), and then again in your `persistData()` function (after `file` is re-initialized)?

Comment: @PaF, I checked, they are exactly the same (in constructor & in persist function)

Comment: @Leem.fin This means that the `getDir` call in your constructor is failing to create the directory, while the `getDir` call in your `persistData` function creates the dir successfully. When are you doing the construction (`new MyClass(context)`)? I'm guessing at this point the app is still not allowed to write to its internal data folder, for some reason. At what stage in the app's lifetime is this construction happening (e.g. app's `onCreate` method)?

Comment: @PaF, the new MyClass(context) is called in a singleton class's constructor. Then that singleton's function calls my.persistData() . The singleton is not in onCreate() but after it.

Comment: Sorry, but we've come to the point where I can't help without seeing the actual code. Sounds like your workaround resolves the issue anyway, so you should just keep using it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about this but you might need to call

```
if(!file.exists())    
    file.createNewFile()
```

before opening the FileOutputStream

Comment: I tried your suggestion, I got "IOException: open failed: ENOENT", which complains about java.io.File.createNewFile()

Answer (score 0):

Before accessing the file check if file exists or not

```
 File dir = context.getDir("dataDir", context.MODE_PRIVATE);
 if(! dir.exists()){
     if(dir.mkdir());
 }

File file = new File(dir, "myData");
 if(! file .exists()){
     if(file .mkdir());
 }
```